# phpmyadmin will not authenticate mysql account -cannot log into phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

From a command line, I can log into mysql like this:

### sudo mysql -u myuser -h 127.0.0.1 -p

(fyi, cannot use localhost, must use ip)
And I can get to:
http://myhost.com/phpmyadmin/

but I cannot log in with myuser account -get repeated login prompts and finnally "Access denied".

So I tried editing: /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
added:

1. $cfg['Servers'][1]['host']='127.0.0.1';
2. $cfg['Servers'][1]['ssl']=false;
3. $cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type']='config';
4. $cfg['Servers'][1]['only_db']=array('mydb');
5. $cfg['Servers'][1]['user']='myuser';
6. $cfg['Servers'][1]['password']='mypassword';

restarted apache and still got the same problem.
I also tried auth_type: 'http' with no user set and it did not change things.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dit you make that account or is it default. If it is default you also can try to leave the password blank. Another question are you working local or on domain?

Comment: have a domain but app uses localhost since its on the same server.

Comment: I think I just plain do not have the right kind of account to setup phpmyadmin.  I skipped the create database part because I already had a database, but perhaps phpmyadmin needs one of its own?

Comment: Perhaps your phpMyAdmin installation is secured by some other means (usually a `.htaccess` file) provided by a package manager or other packaged installation. How have you installed phpMyAdmin (from source yourself, through a distribution package manager, as part of XAMPP/WAMP/etc)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to login from command line but not from phpmyadmin I experienced disk full issue.
Try :
df -h 
if your disk is full mysql is not able to create temp file (such as session files)

Comment: I saw that idea on another post and checked -the disk has plenty of free space